# How to copy values from a dataframe and paste them into the same dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In R and using dplyr, I am calculating certain figures for housing stock and the future of said stock. I have ready values for the column `year == "2020"`. Starting from `year == "2021"`, there are missing values in columns `n`, `m2`, and `m3`. `year` is the current year where we are observing the housing stock and `agegroup` is the age of the houses.

For houses younger than 50 years old (shown later in my code as `add_removal == FALSE`, see also the chart at the end of the question), I  need to move values from 2020 to 2021, then from 2021 to 2022 and so forth.

For example, the row with `application == "in_total"`, `agegroup == "1980 - 1989"`, and `year == "2021"` should receive values `n = 331504.753`, `m2 = 100567072`, and `m3 = 469347236` from the year 2020.

In short, how do I pick values from a dataframe and copy these values to another location in the dataframe? dplyr would be preferable but not required. Many thanks.

This is a sample of the dataframe I am working with:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(
  list(
    application =
      c(
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "in_total",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "non-residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential",
        "residential"
      ),
    agegroup = c(
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "2023",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "2023",
      "- 1920",
      "1921 - 1939",
      "1940 - 1959",
      "1960 - 1969",
      "1970 - 1979",
      "1980 - 1989",
      "1990 - 1999",
      "2000 - 2009",
      "2010 - 2019",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "2023"
    ),
    year = c(
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2020",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2021",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2022",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023",
      "2023"
    ),
    n = c(
      107888.12042231,
      98476.4155941322,
      315684.628977713,
      168008.573048468,
      243925.511623518,
      331504.753048448,
      220979.115873231,
      229905.617147809,
      163215.010761228,
      12371.0533724809,
      34126.0242055754,
      21027.9274600946,
      46468.8989782358,
      42069.5035100594,
      54203.0999047094,
      114811.937988521,
      105544.545466623,
      92346.3590620942,
      52114.8656545615,
      2680.68242307823,
      78107.9128524768,
      74051.3072354794,
      242386.242221213,
      122958.758705404,
      178003.854473847,
      225740.975223268,
      141780.394616868,
      148474.808036318,
      105370.330901508,
      9690.3709494027,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      11049.7984222242,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      1748.05652341881,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      9301.74189880541,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      10917.0614212177,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      1733.83990218778,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      9183.22151902988,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      10770.4157245627,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      1717.69765743056,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      9052.7180671321
    ),
    m2 = c(
      23109128.5478484,
      22196304.8610076,
      57589742.4452604,
      57443570.894227,
      92494571.7747885,
      100567072.006778,
      66571606.8211262,
      73158895.8987782,
      63431932.5965308,
      5783360.57498739,
      13948675.7443116,
      10978770.6577623,
      24130096.9702668,
      25867600.3071861,
      33498527.0310566,
      44559705.0599253,
      28847809.2036104,
      35388017.9183034,
      30203413.0001785,
      2945781.10725852,
      12257272.6149513,
      13157893.5794275,
      35788682.8650978,
      32322466.080688,
      53683485.9326435,
      53661317.4822734,
      36307184.7130895,
      38050206.791632,
      33911699.8939411,
      2837579.46772888,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      4612476.70884812,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2547833.77339036,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2064642.93545776,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      4580235.22809618,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2534820.14707615,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2045415.08102003,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      4542545.00231316,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2519336.94791605,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      2023208.05439711
    ),
    m3 = c(
      152748914.172737,
      139423742.806407,
      446948969.994267,
      237867959.923764,
      345351804.199351,
      469347235.571828,
      312864102.853603,
      325502318.92147,
      231081193.859724,
      28688693.2921012,
      93185442.3128638,
      57419425.9925419,
      126889229.140593,
      114876121.192781,
      148008446.835817,
      313508575.150971,
      288202783.1244,
      252163459.280964,
      142306258.058106,
      18335100.8424912,
      66702117.5761464,
      63237882.3284824,
      206991520.283171,
      105003568.533131,
      152010642.667496,
      192776897.003194,
      121076754.02348,
      126793608.240938,
      89983510.5580722,
      10353592.44961,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      23301021.9219309,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      15788837.0227108,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      7512184.8992201,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      23149997.8797537,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      15707750.0281322,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      7442247.85162147,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      22972807.1197853,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      15611334.396046,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      NA,
      7361472.72373938
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-138L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

The following code chunk shows the furthest I have managed come to solve this. In the following format or any other, how would it be possible to detect condition `(as.numeric(year) - 50 < agegroup & is.na(n))` and then add the value from the previous year to the current year?

Columns `yearminus50` and `add_removal` are simply there to help with the calculations. I am quite sure their function could be integrated into the code in some clever way.

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    yearminus50 = as.numeric(year) - 50,
    add_removal = as.numeric(year) - 50 > agegroup,
    n = case_when(
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 > agegroup & is.na(n)) ~ 111, # placeholder
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 < agegroup & is.na(n)) ~ -1, # value from previous year here
      TRUE ~ n),
    m2 = case_when(
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 > agegroup & is.na(m2)) ~ 222, # placeholder
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 < agegroup & is.na(m2)) ~ -1, # value from previous year here
      TRUE ~ m2),
    m3 = case_when(
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 > agegroup & is.na(m3)) ~ 333, # placeholder
      (as.numeric(year) - 50 < agegroup & is.na(m3)) ~ -1, # value from previous year here
      TRUE ~ m3))
```

`df1` with its missing data looks like this (this is a partial sample):

| application | agegroup | year | n | m2 | m3 | yearminus50 | add_removal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| in_total | - 1920 | 2021 | 111.000 | 222 | 333 | 1971 | TRUE |
| in_total | 1921 - 1939 | 2021 | 111.000 | 222 | 333 | 1971 | TRUE |
| in_total | 1940 - 1959 | 2021 | 111.000 | 222 | 333 | 1971 | TRUE |
| in_total | 1960 - 1969 | 2021 | 111.000 | 222 | 333 | 1971 | TRUE |
| in_total | 1970 - 1979 | 2021 | 111.000 | 222 | 333 | 1971 | TRUE |
| in_total | 1980 - 1989 | 2021 | -1.000 | -1 | -1 | 1971 | FALSE |
| in_total | 1990 - 1999 | 2021 | -1.000 | -1 | -1 | 1971 | FALSE |
| in_total | 2000 - 2009 | 2021 | -1.000 | -1 | -1 | 1971 | FALSE |
| in_total | 2010 - 2019 | 2021 | -1.000 | -1 | -1 | 1971 | FALSE |
| in_total | 2020 | 2021 | -1.000 | -1 | -1 | 1971 | FALSE |
| in_total | 2021 | 2021 | 11049.798 | 4612477 | 23301022 | 1971 | FALSE |

Comment: `df1 %>% group_by(application, agegroup) %>% tidyr::fill(n:m3) %>% ungroup() `? Should work presuming data is sorted by year, so the default fill direction "down" will populate missing rows with prior values.

Comment: what Jon said, but also, what's the deal with the *'df1 with its missing data looks like this (this is a partial sample)'* table? there are no rows with n == 111.000, so idk where that data came from

Comment: Thank you @JonSpring your suggestion seems to work. I was too rigid in my thinking, this was easy and concise. If you'd like to add an answer I would be glad to set is as the solution to this question.